# will apple refuse my none unit-testing application?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, xcode4.2

Well I'm new to Objective-C and programming at all (beginner) ... and I've done an iPhone app on Xcode .. I didn't knew about unit-testing before .. when I test my app it gives me error that includes the unit-tests are not implemented yet because I've checked the unit tests box in the start of making my application .. what if I've unchecked that box .. will apple refuse my application or what ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple will not reject an application without unit tests.